Scrape data using selenium on a click in webpage
I would like to scrape all exhibitor names and information from this link: https://asiatechxsg.com/exhibitors/ into a csv file.
So far, I have:
exhibitor_names = []
exhibitor_info = []
exhibitor_web = []
exhibitor_linkedin = []
exhibitor_twitter = []
exhibitor_email = []
exhibitor_contact = []
exhibitor_booth = []

import time
import logging
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

# Initialize WebDriver and Options
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://asiatechxsg.com/exhibitors/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, "IframeModule_iframe__JCvXg")))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
match=False
while(match==False):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    last_element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='Singapore Centre for Social Enterprise, raiSE Ltd']")
    if (len(last_element) >= 1):
        match=True

# Extract all exhibitor links
exhibitor_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/widget/event/asia-tech-x-singapore-2024/exhibitor/')]")
logger.info(f"Found {len(exhibitor_links)} exhibitor links.")

for index, link in enumerate(exhibitor_links):
    try:
        # Click on each exhibitor link
        link.click()
        logger.info(f"Clicked on exhibitor link {index + 1}/{len(exhibitor_links)}")

        # Wait for the div containing the paragraphs to be visible
        info_div = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sc-dd6f9f7c-0 hIHCKf']")))
        
        # Extract all the paragraph texts within the div
        paragraphs = info_div.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")
        info_text = '\n'.join([p.text for p in paragraphs])
        
        # Extract the exhibitor name
        name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='sc-a13c392f-0 sc-85df61db-4 feepZZ eErKol']").text

        # Append the extracted information to the lists
        exhibitor_names.append(name)
        exhibitor_info.append(info_text)
        logger.info(f"Extracted information for {name}.")

        # Navigate back to the main exhibitors page
        driver.back()
        logger.info("Navigated back to the main exhibitors page.")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Failed to process exhibitor link: %s", e)
        continue

# Close the WebDriver
driver.quit()

# Create a DataFrame
exhibitors_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Exhibitor Name': exhibitor_names,
    'Description': exhibitor_info,
})

# Print the extracted information
print(exhibitors_df)

The get names part works fine. The problem comes when I try to get everything else (to fill up the initialised empty lists). Running the above code gives me:

INFO:root:Found 860 exhibitor links. INFO:root:Clicked on exhibitor
link 1/860 ERROR:root:Failed to process exhibitor link: Message:
Stacktrace:   GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65B8C1522+60802]    (No symbol)
[0x00007FF65B83AC22]  (No symbol) [0x00007FF65B6F7CE4]    (No symbol)
[0x00007FF65B746D4D]  (No symbol) [0x00007FF65B746E1C]    (No symbol)
[0x00007FF65B78CE37]  (No symbol) [0x00007FF65B76ABBF]    (No symbol)
[0x00007FF65B78A224]  (No symbol) [0x00007FF65B76A923]    (No symbol)
[0x00007FF65B738FEC]  (No symbol) [0x00007FF65B739C21]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65BBC41BD+3217949]  GetHandleVerifier
[0x00007FF65BC06157+3488183]

I'm new to selenium...I don't really know if what I'm doing is right. It doesn't work so obviously I'm doing something wrong. I just don't know what. Please help. Thank you in advance

You will need to select the button/link element and call .click() on it - what have you tried?

@Grismar I have included my code in the question. That is what I have tried

It looks like you're explicitly trying to locate a div with classnames 'sc-dd6f9f7c-0 hIHCKf' but when I look at the site in a browser, such a div never loads. It seems like this classname is generated on the fly, and doesn't reliably appear, certainly not for every exhibitor. Since you wait.until it appears, your code times out and you can get the error you shared. Waiting for the data to load is a good idea, but you'll need to find something more reliable to wait for.
